SNR: Does noise prevent resolving signal peaks in a spectrum via its "amount" or its variance (wiggliness of noise floor)?
I’m trying to understand how noise obscures our ability to detect peaks in a spectrum and how this is captured by SNR. Let’s say we have a power spectrum plotted on a linear scale, picking up broadband white noise with mean 10 (in the frequency domain; a linear fit to the pure noise spectrum would just be a line at y=10). Then we turn on some signal generator which would (in the absence of noise) cause a peak with power 1 at 100Hz. Powers add, so the combined power at 100Hz is going to be a random with the same distribution as the noise except now with mean 11. SNR here is going to be signal power (1) over expected value of the noise (10) so 0.1. This is quite low, so it should be very difficult/impossible for me to say that the power of my signal is 1 if I’m only given the spectrum. Now let’s say my white noise now has mean 0.1. Now my SNR is 10; much better, and if given just the spectrum, I expect I’ll be able to say with much more confidence how strong/what frequency the signal is.
My question is how to make this rigorous: why exactly is it easier to resolve the signal peak in the high SNR scenario? Is it due to the lower AMOUNT of noise (e.g. less power)? That’s certainly what directly factors into the SNR calculation. It also lines up with my original lay intuition as one of noise as being some kind of muck that you pour over a painting. The more muck, the harder it is to discern the features in the painting. But once I started thinking about it, I realized I don’t think it’s the noise power itself (at least, not directly) that’s the issue: it’s the variance of the noise. After all, let’s say our “noise” was a collection of pure sine wave generators, one at each frequency bin in our spectrum. Then (up to some limit due to our microphone/measurement system) it shouldn’t matter what the "noise" power/SNR was. Our “noise” floor is perfectly flat with some peak poking out of it at 100Hz; this peak will be equally discernable in the spectrum no matter what the y value/power of the perfectly flat noise floor is. The difference between this and the white noise is that we don't know what the noise power is at 100Hz -- we just know its mean/expected value by integrating over the rest of the spectrum, but at any given bin it could vary significantly. In my intuition painting analogy, this would be something like the observation that if we increased intensity of all colors in a painting by the same amount, it'd look different, but features would still be just as resolvable in all locations (assuming we haven't reached saturation of intensity at any pixel). The reason noise obscures a signal is because we don't know exactly what effect its going to have from bin to bin; if it had the same effect on all bins, we could just subtract that effect off and we're good to go.
Assuming this is correct, my question then becomes: if SNR is a quantitative measure of our ability to resolve features, why is the noise power/expected value/"amount" of noise the quantity used in SNR calculation rather than the variance/some measure of the variability of the noise?
P.S. ChatGPT provided the following answer: if the real/imaginary parts of the FT of the noise are each normally distributed, then the power is (roughly) the square of these two R.V. added together, meaning noise power is a chi-square R.V. which has the property that its variance is directly proportional to the mean. But this smells fishy, and still leaves the question of we wouldn't use a different measure that directly takes the noise variability into account rather than SNR.
